# Pandas selecting rows where string 'exceeds' an accepted data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a dataframe that looks like this (stock trades), except I have 100+ transactions/rows:

```
id, transaction, symbol, qty, price
1, YOU SOLD, NSYS, -20, $5.70
2, YOU SOLD, LMPX, -20, $14.89
3, YOU SOLD, DKNG, -5, $40.5126
4, YOU SOLD 20238F0JQC, ALYA, -10, $1.98
5, YOU BOUGHT, KMDA, 10, $11.69
6, YOU SOLD 20237GVGCW, CLPS,-1, $3.79
```

I want to select only the rows that have 'YOU SOLD ...' ignoring other rows that have 'YOU SOLD', 'YOU BOUGHT'.

So in this data set, I would only want to grab rows 4 and 6.

What is the best way to do this without having to iterate thru rows.

Thanks
-Ven

Comment: Please explain the criteria better. I see that each row has either SOLD or BOUGHT

Comment: Also, please provide the columns names

Comment: @gtomer - thank you for the suggestions, I updated the question.

Comment: The criteria is still not clear. Why not choose 1,2,3?

Comment: @gtomer I'm building a trading a system and want to remove transactions like 4 and 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpliest is chain condition for select all rows with subtring and not match string like:

```
df1 = df[df['transaction'].str.contains('YOU SOLD') & df['transaction'].ne('YOU SOLD')]
print (df1)
   id          transaction   symbol    qty  price
3   4  YOU SOLD 20238F0JQC     ALYA    -10  $1.98
5   6  YOU SOLD 20237GVGCW  CLPS,-1  $3.79   None
```

Or change value for selecting with space:

```
df1 = df[df['transaction'].str.contains('YOU SOLD\s+')]
print (df1)
   id          transaction   symbol    qty  price
3   4  YOU SOLD 20238F0JQC     ALYA    -10  $1.98
5   6  YOU SOLD 20237GVGCW  CLPS,-1  $3.79   None
```